# Can't use an undefined value as a filehandle reference

Tags: perl, libcurl

first off I've searched the forums and didn't find exactly my issue.
I'm running Ubuntu with perl 5.10 installed.

I'm receiving the following error after executing my script:

```
 "Can't use an undefined value as filehandle reference at scraper.pl line 17"
```

Here is my script....

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -W
use strict;
use warnings;

use WWW::Curl::Easy;


my $curl = WWW::Curl::Easy->new;

$curl->setopt(CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
$curl->setopt(CURLOPT_URL, 'http://something.com');


my $response_body;
$curl->setopt(CURLOPT_WRITEDATA,\$response_body);

my $return_code = $curl->perform;

if ($return_code == 0)
{
  my $response_code = $curl->getinfo(CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
  print ("Success ".$response_code);
}
else
{
  # Error Code
  print ("An error occured: ".$return_code." ".$curl->strerror($return_code)." ".$curl->errbuf."\n");
}

# EOF
```

Any help here would be much appreciated.

Thanks,

Ben

Comment: where do you receive the error?

Comment: @Kevin at scraper.pl line 15. ;)

Comment: Sorry... the error occurs on line 15... my $return_code = $curl->perform;

Comment: btw... the code I used is verbatim from http://search.cpan.org/~szbalint/WWW-Curl-4.15/lib/WWW/Curl.pm

Comment: Run with `Carp::Always` and get a full stack trace of the error. (`perl -MCarp::Always the_script.pl`)

Comment: Just installed Carp::Always and ran my script as you suggested (perl -MCarp::Always scraper.pl)

Unfortunately I did not see any more debug output... the same error was simply retuned ("Can't use an undefined value as filehandle reference at scraper.pl line 15
")

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In place of:

```
my $response_body;
$curl->setopt(CURLOPT_WRITEDATA,\$response_body);
```

do:

```
my $response_body = '';
open(my $fileb, ">", \$response_body);
$curl->setopt(CURLOPT_WRITEDATA,$fileb);
```

If you check the documentation for the version of WWW-Curl you actually have installed, I think you'll see it passes a filehandle, not a scalar reference.

Alternatively, upgrade WWW-Curl.

Also note that -W is not generally advisable; often modules will disable warnings for a particular scope and the capital W switch prevents that.   Use -w instead (or just `use warnings;` for your own code, which you are already doing).

Comment: Just asking... why has the community chosen to support this comment regarding a solution when the one I've designated as solving the problem remains unpopular?

Comment: @Bnjmn: at a guess, because the other one presents a workaround to you having read the wrong documentation rather than explaining that you did?

Comment: Also, using curl to get something into a temp file is a little odd.

Comment: thank you for the clarification. I agree that using a temp file is not ideal as wget would have been a much more direct approach. I will adjust my endorsed solution accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use WWW::Curl::Easy;
use File::Temp qw/tempfile/;

my $response_body = tempfile();

my $curl = WWW::Curl::Easy->new;

$curl->setopt(CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
$curl->setopt(CURLOPT_URL, 'http://yiddele.com/categoryindex.aspx');

#$curl->setopt(CURLOPT_WRITEDATA,\$response_body);
$curl->setopt(CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, \$response_body);

my $return_code = $curl->perform;

if ($return_code == 0)
{
  my $response_code = $curl->getinfo(CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
  print ("Success ".$response_code);
}
else
{
  # Error Code
  print ("An error occured: ".$return_code." ".$curl->strerror($return_code)." ".$curl->errbuf."\n");
}

# EOF
```

Output is:

```
Success 200
```

Comment: thank you d5e5, you have remedied the problem. Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: This post has been demoted as the suggested solution as it represents a somewhat awkward workaround however it still provides the intended results, thus I've voted for it.

Comment: Thanks Bnjmn. After I posted the above I saw ysth had posted an answer 4 minutes earlier which I voted for because it included an explanation. Also I hadn't seen yet the Curl.pm file installed along with WWW::Curl::Easy, one level up from the Curl folder containing Easy.pm. It contains examples using the various methods, including perform.

Answer (score 0):

There is bad code at:

```
print ("Success ".$response_code);
```

Look at the documentation for [print](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/print.html): due to the way arguments are parsed when you use parentheses, the first argument will be interpreted to be a filehandle, which is *not* what you intended.  In your code, the parentheses are unnecessary; just pass a concatenated string, or better, avoid the concatenation and pass a list of strings:

```
print 'Success ', $response_code;
```

Also, please *please* always include `use strict; use warnings;` at the top of *every* script you write. You will discover that many errors are highlighted that may otherwise remain hidden for quite some time, and it also saves everyone's time when you catch an error before ever having to ask on Stack Overflow. :)

Comment: Thanks for the input... a real amateur mistake :(

Comment: @Bnjmn: not if that line never gets executed: :p

Comment: @David - as you can see, the community fixes problems BEFORE they occur ;)

Comment: I agree with the sentiment that `print 'Success', $response_code;` is better form, but is it really the case that the parens will cause an error? A simple `perl -We 'my $val = "bar\n"; print ("foo ".$bar);'` works fine for me on Cygwin.

Comment: so I hate to be a pain but I made the changes in accordance with Ether's recommendations and unfortunately still received the same error :(

Comment: Changed my script to include use strict; and use warnings;
unfortunately the same error was produced but occurred two lines lower than before without any new meaningful debug output.

Answer (score 0):

```
my $response_body;
$curl->setopt(CURLOPT_WRITEDATA,\$response_body);
```

You've declared `$response_body`, but haven't assigned a value to it. I assume that this would work if you made it a string.

```
my $response_body = "";
```

That said, I can't be sure as I can't reproduce the error. Perhaps installing a newer version of the module would help too.

Comment: Thank you for that response, I know perl is especially generous in terms of variable initialization and so the fix you proposed didn't solve the issue. I also downloaded the latest version of the Curl module and made sure that my perl interpreter was also quite recent as previous posts in the forums reported issues with older versions of perl.

Quick update, when I do change $response_body to the empty string the interpreter error changes and says "Bad filehandle: at scraper.pl line 15"

Comment: From that comment, isn't it possible that $curl->setopt expects a filehandle as its second argument, rather than a reference to a scalar? If you don't mind, try this:
open my $fh, '>', \$response_body or die "$!";
$curl->setopt(CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, $fh);

EDIT: The docs imply this shouldn't matter, though.

Comment: @Hugmeir: but he's checking the newest docs, not the docs of the version he has.  4.11 at least requires a filehandle, not a scalar ref.

Answer (score 0):

```
        use Data::Printer ;
        use URI::Encode qw(uri_encode uri_decode);
        use JSON ();
        use JSON::Parse ':all' ;
        use WWW::Curl;
        use HTTP::Response ;

        use utf8 ;
        use Carp ;
        use Cwd qw ( abs_path ) ;
        use Getopt::Long;

         use WWW::Curl::Easy;

         my $curl = WWW::Curl::Easy->new;
         $curl->setopt(WWW::Curl::Easy::CURLOPT_HEADER(),1);
         $curl->setopt(WWW::Curl::Easy::CURLOPT_URL(), 'https://www.pivotaltracker.com/services/v5/me?fields=%3Adefault');
         $curl->setopt(WWW::Curl::Easy::CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER() , ['X-TrackerToken: ' . $TOKEN]  );
         #$curl->setopt(WWW::Curl::Easy::CURLOPT_POST(), 1);

         # A filehandle, reference to a scalar or reference to a typeglob can be used here.
         my $response_body;
         $curl->setopt(WWW::Curl::Easy::CURLOPT_WRITEDATA(),\$response_body);

         # Starts the actual request
         my $ret = $curl->perform;


         if ($ret == 0) {

              print("Transfer went ok\n");
              my $response_code = $curl->getinfo(CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
              # judge result and next action based on $response_code

              $response_body = HTTP::Response->parse($response_body);
              print("Received response: $response_body\n");
              p($response_body);
              my $json_data = $response_body->content ;

              $json_data = JSON->new->utf8->decode($json_data);
              p($json_data);

         } else {
             # Error code, type of error, error message
              print("An error happened: $ret ".$curl->strerror($ret)." ".$curl->errbuf."\n");
         }

        # my $cmd='curl -X GET -H "X-TrackerToken: ' . "$TOKEN" . '" "https://www.pivotaltracker.com/services/v5/me?fields=%3Adefault"' ;
        # my $json_str = `$cmd`;
        # p($json_str);
        # my $json_data = JSON->new->utf8->decode($json_str);
        # p($json_data);
```